# How to extract number with hyphen using regex

Tags: python-3.x

```
import re
h = "WO - 174-819"
b = re.search("WO\s*-\s*(\d+)",h)
print(b.group(1))
```

Is there any solution to get number with hyphen Sol: 174-819

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you have now?

Comment: I need 174-819 but i get 174

Comment: Why don't you add `-\d+` to the regular expression?

Comment: NoneType' object has no attribute 'group

Comment: I don't get that error. What did you do now?

Comment: b = re.search("WO\s*-\s*(-\d+)",h)

Comment: Obviously don't *replace* `\d+` by `-\d+` but *add* `-d\+` to get `\d+-\d+`.

Comment: What about this number 174-819-74

Comment: That's a whole new problem. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

you need one more hyphen

```
re.search(r"WO\s*-\s*(\d+-\d+)",h)
```

great way to test regex: https://regex101.com/